# How to add Siri custom command to control the iOS app with SiriKit

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

I have an iOS app which wants to integrate the SiriKit function.
Is it possible to add a Siri command to control one function of its?

The kind of the app is about a map/navigation app. The api like "Open the map on XXX", "Navigate to XXX", etc.

I have a study. The standard Intents in SiriKit is below.

=== Standard Intents ===

- Car Commands
- Lists and Notes
- Media
- Messaging
- Payments
- Restaurant Reservations
- Ride Booking
- VoIP Calling
- Workouts

And I think add to Siri ShortCut is not useful.

I figure out the behavior of Google Map is the best possible. I just install it from the store and Call "Hey, Siri" -> "Google Map navigate to XXX". I dont add the custom action to Siri ShortCut.

Does anyone know how to do that? Please help me or give me some hint about. thanks.